# how to read screen resolution - and change this resolution?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to read screen resolution - and change this resolution ?

ex: i read 800X600 and i want to change to 1024X768

in WinForm - C#

Comment: @Gold: it's not necessary to include the language (C#) in the title, since it's already in a tag. Same for winforms.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371446/how-to-change-desktop-screen-resolution

Answer (score 2):

First of all: *Which* screen? You know that there can be multiple ones.

From Windows Forms you can use the [`Screen` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) to retrieve the dimensions of a specific screen. You can use the [`ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183413.aspx) to change the resolution of a display. I don't think there is a purely managed way to do it.